# Is there a java command that can close a primefaces overlay panel?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there a java command that can close a primefaces overlay panel? Or is there a way to make a button inside of an overlay panel close the panel when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that (in PrimeFaces 7.0 at least) a `p:commandButton` that merely updates the form or any component outside the overlayPanel will close the overlayPanel. For example,

```
<p:commandButton value="Close" update="myform" />
```

My only concern is that I can't find documentation that explains specifically that or why this happens, so I'm a little hesitant to depend on it. On the other hand, it seems to do a cleaner job than `onclick="PF('panelWidgetVar').hide();"`, which tends to blank my browser window and redraw the whole page, whereas `update` alone seems to refresh just those parts of the page I need updated.

Answer (score 6):

You can easy add a button to your overlaypanel to close it e.g.

```
<p:overlayPanel widgetVar="myOverlayPanel" ... >
  <p:commandButton ... onComplete="PF('myOverlayPanel').hide(); ... />
</p:overlayPanel>
```

Also you can do this in Java

```
private void doSomething() {
  RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
  ctx.execute("PF('myOverlayPanel').hide();");
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me in PF 6.2, except that I had to use the `onclick` event instead of `onComplete`.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like (haven't tested myself)

client side only solution

```
<p:commandButton id="basic" onclick="jQuery('#IdOfThePanel').hide()"></p:commandButton>
```

or client side + server side

jsf:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{myBean.doSomething}"/>
```

java:

```
public void doSomething(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("jQuery('#IdOfThePanel').hide()");
}
```

take a look here on executing js from java

[Executing Javascript from Server Side](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/requestContext.jsf)

p.s  maybe instead of IdOfThePanel you'll have to add some prefix like formID:IdOfThePanel... depends on your case...

Edit: instead of `jQuery('#IdOfThePanel').hide()` just use `panelWidgetVar.hide()` or in more recent PrimeFaces versions, `PF('panelWidgetVar').hide()`

Comment: overlayPanelWidgetVar.hide() would be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside p:overlayPanel tag and set p:effect 'for' attrib with overlayPanel id, use the appendToBody=true.

```
 <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e">
        <p:effect type="slide"  for="idOverlayPanel" event="click">
            <f:param name="mode" value="'hide'"/>
            <f:param name="direction" value="'right'"/>
        </p:effect>
    </p:commandLink>
```

Without effect parameters

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-close" >
    <p:effect type="slide"  for="idOverlayPanel" event="click"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

You can change slide effect to anotherone, icon style class too.

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with jQuery and css. please check below code

```
<p:overlayPanel widgetVar="overlay" showEffect="blind" showCloseIcon="true" styleClass="lane-overlay" dynamic="true" dismissable="true" hideEffect="blind">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".closeIcon").click(function(){
$(".lane-overlay").hide();
});
});
</script>
<p:commandButton value="close"  styleClass="closeIcon"/>
`enter code here`
```